# Is it possible to adjust image sizes via viewport in Android e-mail client?

Tags: android, html, email, html-email

I have an html e-mail where a 625px banner image gets cut off on the right size using an HTC Android device. I've tried to change the viewport without any success.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

My understanding is because of the large number of device sizes using media queries that target specific sizes can be cause unintended issues.

Is this possible in the default e-mail client and if so can someone recommend an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using media queries?

```
<style type="text/css">
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
body img.banner {max-width: 300px !important; height: auto !important;}
}
</style>
```

With the image having a class of "banner" is always successful for me.

Comment: Had tried it before, but not in conjunction with using a class just to adjust the image -- perfect solution.